# Need Optimize TIMESTAMPDIFF query

Tags: mysql, optimization

Hi i have little long time query which takes almost 400ms .

this is my query

```
 SELECT id, `from` 
 FROM messages 
 WHERE `to` = ? 
 AND `to_viewed` = '0' 
 AND `to_deleted` = '0'
 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,created,?)< 20 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,created,?)>= 0
```

How can i optimize this ?

obs  i have no idex .

**EDIT to show my EXPLAIN**

```
  id  select_type  table    type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows Extra
   1  SIMPLE       messages ALL  created  NULL  NULL  NULL    10   Using where
```

Comment: We need to see the CREATE TABLE statement too. (I've a feeling I mentioned this already)

Comment: Are there only 10 rows in the table?

Comment: @RickJames many but maybe its about timediff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have an index on the `created` column. Then use

```
AND created BETWEEN ? AND DATE_ADD(?, INTERVAL 20 SECOND);
```

An index can't be used when you perform a calculation on the column. So you should calculate the ends of the time range and then compare the column to that.

Comment: Thanks barmar :) it decreased to 280ms :) .

Comment: @ScooterDaraf I would have expected a greater improvement. Consider  providing the CREATE TABLE statement AND the EXPLAIN for the query.

Comment: i have other query should i create new post or its ok to edit and add it here ?

Comment: Create a new question, unless it's a minor addition to this one.

Comment: @ScooterDaraf EXPLAIN [YOUR QUERY HERE]; Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You don't put the `[` in there. He was just using that syntax to indicate a placeholder.

Comment: No he didn't. `[YOUR QUERY HERE]` gets replaced with your query.

Comment: You should learn how to use your tools. `EXPLAIN` is explained in the MySQL documentation, it has examples.

Comment: You can't explain a query with placeholders, you have to use the real values.

Comment: @Strawberry edited my answer barmar . i would just say that i used SECOND in EXPLAIN didnt work with SEC .